# How are social security numbers protected when someone has a judgment?

Tags: united-states

Creditor can order the debtors  1099, w2, income statements etc with a court order.

How are the debtors ssns going to be protected?

Comment: SSNs aren’t exactly secure information to begin with - it’s fairly easy to construct one for a person you have enough info about.

Comment: Is this specific to Nevada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not, necessarily. A particular state may impose protective requirements on businesses, but there is no general-purpose pan-US (federal) law prohibiting people from collecting and storing your social security number. [Connecticut](https://www.lawserver.com/law/state/connecticut/ct-laws/connecticut_statutes_42-471) has a relatively strong law which requires safeguarding the personal information of another, including the requirement for a privacy policy. This applies to "Any person who collects Social Security numbers in the course of business" – there is a $500 fine for *intentionally* violating the law. However, government agencies are not subject to the law. Most states don't have such a law, as far as I know.